# Is jack and jill for android compatible with byte code weaving?

Tags: android, android-build, bytecode-manipulation, android-jack-and-jill

I just read the new blog post of @eric lafortune about Jack and Jill's new compiler on Android. 
http://www.saikoa.com/blog/the_upcoming_jack_and_jill_compilers_in_android

And as I am working intensively on a bunch of new technologies built on byte code weaving for Android, I am wondering if anyone has any idea if byte code weaving would still work with this new tool chain.

Comment: Its possible that jack will also be used for [multidex support](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/multidex/+/602c6ca8cae4718ba8ff9f65e53305d002479359/library/src/android/support/multidex/MultiDexExtractor.java)

Answer (score 0):

From the article you mentioned:

> Since the toolchain still supports both java source code and java
>   bytecode, existing libraries can be used without problems. Even tools
>   that **generate or process bytecode during the build process**, such as
>   Dagger, should be fine, with the proper integration.

Bytecode weaving is just bytecode generation/processing, so I think the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: There seem to be a mistake here, dagger doesn't generate byte code, it's annotation processor based, so it generates source code. And this has little to with byte code weaving.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering this myself, but it seems that Kotlin will be a second-class citizen with the new jack and jill compiler unless JetBrains makes an explicit statement that it won't: [Android N Java 8 features (Jack compiler) and Kotlin interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919849/android-n-java-8-features-jack-compiler-and-kotlin-interop)

EDIT: no longer true because Kotlin is a first class citizen and the Jack & Jill project are dead.